# How to construct CMake files to be OS generic but specific too?

Tags: c++, cmake, multiplatform

Actually, my project has this files:

```
/ cmake / CMakeLists.txt
/ sources / {my cpp headers ...}
```

And I construct the "project" (makefile or .sln...) the same way under every OS, at the root of this repository with the command:

```
cmake ./cmake/
```

But it needs some optional settings like the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` different on each OS.

And I have chosen to put this variables in a `/cmake/CMakeCache.txt` but to not commit this file (since it is different between OSs). The dev has to generate (edit) this file on each machine. I only gave some instructions in a readme about this CMakeCache file.

How could I make cmake files generic again, but have this differences in a commited content too?

Comment: I think `CMakeCache.txt` is generated automatically and is not supposed to be edited manually.

Comment: In addition to the platforms you might also have a look onto the concept of CMake toolchains (see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code like this in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -pthread")
elseif(WIN32)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN")
endif()
```

Notes:

- Append your options to ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} so that user-specified settings are also included.
- You cannot use list(APPEND ...) with compiler flags because it uses semicolons to separate parameters (this is why the code above uses set(...) with quotes)
- APPLE is also UNIX, so we need NOT APPLE when we actually mean Linux

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if`s for different platforms directly in your `CMakeLists.txt` files like following:

```
if (APPLE)
  # ...
elseif (UNIX)
  # ...
elseif (WIN32)
  # ...
endif()
```